# Expande button until status change

Tags: javascript

I use an automation testing tool (selenium)

I try to test a page which has this button:

```
<button morearea-controllers="my-list" morearea-expanded="false" class="lpw-reach-text-more link">
```

As a user, when I press **show more** it shows the "show more content". And when there is no more to show, the `morearea-expanded` becomes `true`.

Is there any JavaScript command which could expand the button until the end *(until `morearea-expanded` becomes true)*?

Somehting very general I tried as I found it is from the full button list which I found the list and after that the number of button (but this number is not the same in every page I try to test):

```
document.querySelectorAll('button')
```

is this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[29].click()
```

Comment: Maybe keep invoking button click inside a while loop which will execute until the attribute value is true

Comment: @Developer thank you yes this is right but my first problem is how could I click the button using possible the morearea-controllers="my-list"` instead of a number of the list of buttons?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: Do you mean to find out that specific button in the page? If you have the luxury of using jQuery, then that would be `$("[morearea-controllers='my-list']"`

Comment: @Developer Using this `document.querySelectorAll('button')` I can see which number of the list of buttons is the button I want to click. However I have different pages to test and the number is not standard. So the best work around was to find a javascript code using this attributes morearea-controllers="my-list" which are the only exist in this button. Any idea for this js query. I show in your answer that you use an id but I don't have ids.

Comment: just updated my answer to use the attribute selector. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep invoking the click event in a while loop until the attribute value is "true". Sample using jQuery (function named `automationFunction()`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0,
      $button = $("[morearea-controllers='my-list']");

  /* bad code alert - just for sample purpose */
  $button.click(function() {

    if (count == 5) {
      return;
    } else {
      if (count === 4) {
        $(this).attr("morearea-expanded", true);
         $(this).val("Show Less");
      }
      $("#container").append((count + 1) + "<br/>");
      count++;
    }
  });

  /* automation function */
  $("#btn-automate").click(function() {
    automationFunction();
  });


  var automationFunction = function() {
    count = 0;

    while ($button.attr("morearea-expanded") === "false") {
      $button.click();
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Five items hidden..click on show more to unhide
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn-show-more" morearea-controllers="my-list" morearea-expanded="false" class="lpw-reach-text-more link" value="Show More"> <br/>

<input type="button" id="btn-automate" value="Invoke automation function">
```